# Nicer arithmetics on primitive types in Rust

Tags: casting, rust, integer-arithmetic

Is there a nicer way of doing arithmetics on different primitive types (with auto-promotion up) than explicit casting and unwrapping?

For example in case like:

```
let a: u8 = 1;
let b: u16 = 2;
let c: u32 = 3;
```

can I somehow get rid of all the casts in:

```
let total: u64 = a.to_u64().unwrap() + b.to_u64().unwrap() + c.to_u64().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use `as`:

```
let total: u64 = a as u64 + b as u64 + c as u64;
```

More info on type casting: http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#type-cast-expressions

Comment: Note: in the past, you used to only be able to implement a trait once for a type `impl Add<Right, Result> for Left` was thus only implemented once for `u8`... with `Right` equal to `u8`. With associated types on the way, the `Add` trait could be redesigned so as to be implementable multiple times for a given `Left`, and for example allow `u8 + u32` to yield a `u32`. Associated types are not ready though.